# How to do arithmetic operations on joinExpression in Apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm currently trying to join df1 with df2 where each dataframe has a column named distance and is measured in meters. I want to join where the diff between these two dataframes.distance is <= 10 meters

Something like this
`def1.join(df2, df1("distance") - df2("distance") <= 10).show()`

I've tried to lookup API documentation but I didn't find enough examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a udf in a join to achieve this.

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3)).toDF("distance1")
val df2 = sc.parallelize(Array(10,12,14)).toDF("distance2")

val distanceUdf = spark.udf.register("distanceUdf", ( in1 : Int, in2 : Int)  => {
    Math.abs(in1 - in2)
})
df1.join(df2, distanceUdf(col("distance1"), col("distance2")) <= 10, "inner").show()
```

Comment: How would I define a return type for that function? I'm trying something like this
`def distanceUdf (longA:Double, latA:Double, longAdrop:Double, latAdrop:Double, longB:Double, latB:Double, longBDrop:Double, latBDrop:Double):Int =  {
    //Calculate b.pickup, a.dropoff distance
    val distance = calDistance(longA, latA, longBDrop, latBDrop)

    if(distance < 50) {
         return 0
    } 

    //calculate b.dropoff, a.pickup distance
    val distancePick = calDistance(longAdrop, latAdrop, longB, latB)

    if(distancePick < 20) {
         return 0
    } 
    
    return 1
}`

Comment: Your current return type is fine in your `distanceUdf`. I noticed a typo in my solution ( it should be `val distanceUdf`, not `def distanceUdf` ) - you can do `distanceUdf(col("longA"), col("latA"), col("longAdrop"), col("latAdrop"), col("longB"), col("latB"), col("longBDrop"), col("latBDrop")) == 1` - and if that  evaluates true, the rows will be joined.